# Porque cuando inicio el programa me aparece "System.Random" en vez de un numero?

Tags: c#

Apenas se pocas cosas de programación y quería hacer una tontería, y por cierto utilizo un compilador de la PlayStore, cuando lo compilo en vez de aparecer un número aparece "System.Random".

```
            Random age = new Random();
            
            Console.WriteLine("It has got " + age);
          }
     }
}
```

PSD: el system es Linq y no hay nada más allá más que un Console.WriteLine.

Comment: Porque `age` es una instancia de Random, así que la consola te muestra el className de ese objeto que creaste (es el toString de la clase o como se llame en C#). En ninguna parte estás obteniendo un nuevo número pseudoaleatorio. La clase Random tiene varios métodos para, entre otras cosas, obtener números pseudoaleatorios, pero no los estás usando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La razón es que imprime `System.Random` ya que estas imprimiendo la instancia de la clase `Random()`

```
 Random age = new Random();            
 Console.WriteLine("It has got " + age);
```

salida:

```
It has got System.Random
```

En realidad deberías de usar alguno de estos métodos de la clase `Random`:

- `Next()` Devuelve un entero aleatorio positivo.
- `Next(int)` Devuelve un entero aleatorio positivo menor que el valor máximo especificado.
- `Next(int, int)` Devuelve un entero aleatorio positivo dentro del rango mínimo y máximo especificado (incluye min y excluye max).
- `NextDouble()` Genera un número de punto flotante aleatorio que es mayor o igual a 0,0 y menor que 1,0.
- `NextByte()` Llena la matriz especificada con los bytes aleatorios.

Por ejemplo:

```
 Random age = new Random();
 int valorEdad = age.Next();
 Console.WriteLine("It has got " + valorEdad);
```

salida:

Devolvería un entero aleatorio positivo.

Comment: Next dice que es para números no negativos https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-7.0

Comment: "Next() Devuelve un entero aleatorio positivo." Eliminé la parte de los valores negativos.

Answer (score 4):

Te aparece eso porque [`Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-7.0) no es un número. `Random` es una clase que permite generar números pseudo-aleatorios. Para eso primero instancias la clase, como lo estás haciendo:

```
var rng = new Random();
```

Luego llamas alguna de [las funciones que posee](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-7.0#methods) de acuerdo a lo que quieras generar.

Por ejemplo, para generar un número entre 0 y 2^32 puedes usar `Next`:

```
int num = rng.Next();
```

Hay 2 sobrecargas más de `Next`:

```
// Genera un número entre 0 y 10 (excluido)
rng.Next(10);
// Genera un número entre 10 y 100 (excluido)
rng.Next(10, 100);
```

Lo que devuelve la función `Next` si son `int`. Al llamar a el método `ToString` de un entero de muestra como un número.

`ToString` es llamada implícitamente cuando concatenas otro tipo con un string.

`Random` no tiene una sobrecarga para la función `ToString`. Entonces usa la sobrecarga de [`object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0) que imprime el nombre de la clase.